# Whereis CUDA/Cuda/cuda - Ubuntu 20.4 - cuda install issues

Tags: python, ubuntu, cuda, anaconda, pytorch

I recently switched from windows to ubuntu. I installed miniconda here, created a virtual environment with python 3.8.5, activated that environment and ran

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.0 -c pytorch
```

I ran `torch.cuda.is_available()` and it says True, but when I run which CUDA/Cuda/cuda or whereis CUDA/Cuda/cuda, I get nothing. nvcc is also not working. I think I might have to update bash file. Would someone please be able to guide me.

Also, Do I need to install cuDNN to work on my ML models using CUDA or is that not needed.

Comment: conda will only install the necessary components required to run the ML frameworks they distribute. The "cudatoolkit" package isn't a complete development toolkit and if you are not going to write CUDA code (and it sounds like you are not), then you don't need anything more than what conda installs, **except for a suitable GPU driver**. See the linked duplicate for more information

Comment: Thank You for your response. Can you explain why do I see my CPU utilization 100% and GPU utilization almost 0% when I run my deep learning models on this machine.

Comment: Sorry, no. That will be a property of PyTorch and your code